# Why swap the item order of the knapsack lead to the same solution?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

As far as I know, knapsack problem uses dynamic programming to find the best solution of each item depending on its previous items. This hypothesis assumes that the solution is depending on the order of items. Why the final solution is not depend on the order?

Answer (score 5):

No. The dynamic programming solution for knapsack problem does not depend on the previous items.

When considering whether to put an item into the knapsack or not, we just need to consider the remaining capacity of the knapsack before and after selecting the item. So we loop through all the possible remaining capacity and choose the best one.

```
dp[i][c] = max(dp[i-1][c+w[i]] + v[i], dp[i-1][c])
```

where *dp[i][c]* indicates the maximum possible value after considering the *i*-th item with the remaining capacity of the knapsack equals to *c*. *w[i]* indicates the weight(or volume) of the *i*-th item, and *v[i]* indicates the value of the *i*-th item.

It's not necessary to consider the items in order. Considering the items in order is just for convenience. You can also consider selecting the items in a reversed order, or in a random order.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. What confused me is that `dp[i]` depend on `dp[i-1]`, which makes me believe that item order matters in the dp process. Is there anything wrong with my claim?

Comment: dp[i] does not necessarily comes from dp[i-1]. As I mentioned in my answer, it's just for convenience. If you like, you can calculate the *dp* array from the largest *i*, and that will lead to the formula: dp[i][c] = max(dp[i+1][c+w[i]] + v[i], dp[i+1][c])

Comment: You can also consider the meaning of *dp[i][c]* as "the best answer after considering *i* items with the remaining capacity equals to *c*", instead of "the best answer after considering the first *i* items with the remaining capacity equals to *c*".

Comment: You can also take a look at the unbounded knapsack problem(UKP). It might help you understand further.

Comment: As you say, we can set different orders of the items. But the value of `dp[i]` may be different if we have different items before it. I wonder how could we guarantee that the final result is the same?

Comment: Let's say we have to consider *n* items in total. As the final set of items we considered will always remain the same (there is only one way to choose *n* items from *n* items), the final best answer *dp[n]* will always be the same no matter in which order we consider them. But as there are multiple ways to choose *i(i < n)* items from *n* items, the intermediate results *dp[i]* may be different. But this does not affect the final best result.